# How to get the user input values without calling the entry label name or using the get() methid in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input

I'm pretty new to using python tkinter and I have created a matrix of entries based on user input. Like for example if the user types in 3, the program will output a 3x3 matrix. The issue I'm having is that I'm not able to figure out to extract the user data from the matrix of entries. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

matrix = [[]]

#Validate that the user entered a number
def number():
    input = int(E1.get())
    #Creates a matrix of entries if the user entered a number
    try:
        int(input)
        for x in range(input):
            for y in range(input):
                matrixInput = Entry(root, bg = "white")
                matrixInput.grid(row=10+x, column=1+y, padx=5, pady=5)
                
    
        B2 = Button(root, text="Submit", font = 40, command=storeMatrix)
        B2.grid(row=20, column=1)
            
    except ValueError:
        L2.config(text = "You did not enter a number")


def storeMatrix():
    temp = []
    for x in range(input):
        for y in range(input):
            temp.append(matrixInput.get())



root = Tk()
L1 = Label(root, text="How many people", font = 40)
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)

E1 = Entry(root, bg = "white")
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)


L2 = Label(root, text = '')
L2.grid(row=3, column=1)


B1 = Button(root, text="Submit", font = 40, command=number)
B1.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Any help on how to fix this issue would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use the `get` method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to save all the input fields in a global variable. `matrixInput` is local to the `number()` function, and also only contains the last input that was created.

You can use the `matrix` list for this.

```
matrix = []

def number():
    input = int(E1.get())
    #Creates a matrix of entries if the user entered a number
    try:
        int(input)
        for x in range(input):
            matrixRow = []
            for y in range(input):
                matrixInput = Entry(root, bg = "white")
                matrixInput.grid(row=10+x, column=1+y, padx=5, pady=5)
                matrixRow.append(matrixInput)
            matrix.append(matrixRow)
    
        B2 = Button(root, text="Submit", font = 40, command=storeMatrix)
        B2.grid(row=20, column=1)
            
    except ValueError:
        L2.config(text = "You did not enter a number")

def storeMatrix():
    temp = []
    for x in range(input):
        for y in range(input):
            temp.append(matrix[x][y].get())
```